# Capturar conteúdo a ser colado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso capturar o conteúdo de um texto que será colado em um input, antes da cola acontecer.

Já cheguei a capturar o evento de colagem:

```
$(input).on("paste", function (evt) {
    /* evt contém tudo sobre o evento menos o conteúdo */
});
```

Como obtenho o conteúdo da área de transferência, de maneira cross-browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O conteúdo colado está no próprio `value` do campo. Portanto você pode fazer assim (funcionou no Chrome, não testei nos demais browsers):

```
var input = $('input');
input.on("paste", function (evt) {
    input.val('huehue ' + input.val());
});
```

Tecnicamente você não está interceptando o valor antes, e sim logo após ele ser colado. Mas se a ideia é alterar esse valor, deve ser imperceptível para o usuário. **[Ver demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwmozo4q/)**.

Comment: Funcionou no IE também :)

Answer (score 2):

Achei uma resposta no STOF internacional que ensina uma **gambiarra** pra fazer isto, aparentemente, por questões de segurança, somente desta forma mesmo, senão os sites poderiam copiar a area de transferência de todos os visitantes.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser

Resumindo, esse método faz trocar o foco do campo para outro que esta escondido fora da área visível, startar um setTimeout para liberar o evento de colar e neste evento do setTimeout jogar o valor do campo oculto para o campo visível. neste momento é possível usar o valor.

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2rwezrq/)

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira seria atrasar um pouco a busca pelo valor, não sei se é bem o que você pretende, mais fica como uma opção:

**[Demo: JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9aay4afr/)**

```
$('input').on("paste", function (evt) { 
    setTimeout(function () {
        var dados = $('input').val();
        $('input').val('Aguarde...');

        console.log(dados);
    },100);

});
```